# Switching source control contexts in Visual Studio Team Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer

When I connect to a local Git repository in Visual Studio (2015), Team Explorer shows a Git-specific interface (Changes, Branches, Sync, etc.). When I then connect to a non-Git TFS project, it refuses to acknowledge this switch and continues to show this Git interface (as opposed to the desired TFS interface with My Work, Pending Changes, Source Control Explorer, etc). Whenever I click one of the Git menu options, I get a message saying

> The current page is inactive because you are not connected to a Git team project

which is information of which I am fully aware, but rather than allowing to switch to "TFS mode", it suggests I connect to a Git project.

The only remedy I have found is to close and reopen VS, quite annoying. Is there a way to force this switch?

Comment: How are you connecting to a different project?  You're closing the solution and opening a new one?  Do you have on solution that contains projects of both TFVC and Git?

Comment: Typically clicking the Manage Connections button (the green plug icon). then double clicking on a project. And no...always two completely separate projects.

Comment: Have you remembered to switch Source Control provider in VS (Tools >> Options >> Source Control)?

Comment: I work only with git in vsts and right now VS2015  is doing the same for me the other way around. I cannot work because of it wont clone vsts repositories.

Comment: I have the same issue, just the other way around, as well. I want to access a GIT branch, but VS can only show me "source control explorer" and that TFS stuff.

Comment: What version are you using? I have been working in VS2017 for a while now and have not experienced this, I believe they have finally taken care of it.

Comment: I already had the right Source Control provider selected. A restart of VS resolved it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was having the same issues. It appears as though you have to switch back to the Microsoft Git Plugin and then switch back though Tools -> Options -> Source Control. I think while you can double click on a TFS project, the Team Explorer window doesn't reset unless its done from the options menu.

Comment: As depressing as it is, this seems to be correct. Whats worse, is that TFS was selected, I had to switch it to GIT and back.

Comment: @ChadSchouggins for me have equal situation